# TClientDataSet OnNewRecord vs. AfterInsert

Tags: c++builder, tclientdataset

My question is about inserting records into a table on a firebird database. The table is very simple - it has only 2 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    COL_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_COL_ID PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX IX_COL_ID, 
    COL_ACRONYM VARCHAR(255)
);
```

In my application (c++ Builder XE10) I have the following constellation:

- A `TDataSource` connected to
- A `TClientDataSet` connected to
- A `TDataSetProvider` connected to
- A `TFDTable` connected to
- A `TFDConnection` connected to
- A Firebird Database

The application does the following:

1. Insert a new row using `TClientDataSet.Append();`
2. Edit the newly inserted record.
3. Save this record using `TClientDataSet.ApplyUpdates(-1);`

Everything is working as expected as long as I do the 2nd step manually or by editing the data within the `AfterInsert` event:

```
__fastcall TFormMain::TFormMain(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    ClientDataSet1->Active = true;
}

UnicodeString TFormMain::GenerateGuid( void )
{
    // ...some fancy code creating and returning a GUID...
}

void __fastcall TFormMain::ButtonAppendClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    ClientDataSet1->Append();
}

void __fastcall TFormMain::ButtonSaveClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    ClientDataSet1->ApplyUpdates(-1);
}

void __fastcall TFormMain::ClientDataSet1AfterInsert(TDataSet *DataSet)
{
    DataSet->FieldByName( "COL_ID" )->AsString = GenerateGuid();
    DataSet->FieldByName( "COL_ACRONYM" )->AsString = "Whatever: this works!";
}
```

This works good... so far...

Due to some other changes I decided to move the the auto-creation of data into the `OnNewRecord` event of the `TClientDataSet`:

```
void __fastcall TFormMain::ClientDataSet1NewRecord(TDataSet *DataSet)
{
    DataSet->FieldByName( "COL_ID" )->AsString = GenerateGuid();
    DataSet->FieldByName( "COL_ACRONYM" )->AsString = "Not too good...";
}
```

For the first moment it looked good, because the DB-controls on the GUI have been filled with the correct data. But as soon as I hit the Save Button the data disappeard and the new record has not been stored to the database - as if I cancelled the process.

Secondly I noticed, that if I change one of the columns MANUALLY before executing `ApplyUpdates()`,... then the record is stored.

So I simply added the following line for automatic posting:

```
void __fastcall TFormMain::ClientDataSet1NewRecord(TDataSet *DataSet)
{
    DataSet->FieldByName( "COL_ID" )->AsString = GenerateGuid();
    DataSet->FieldByName( "COL_ACRONYM" )->AsString = "Not too good...";
    DataSet->Post();
}
```

This minor change did its job.
My question now is: WHY?
Does `AfterInsert` automatically post the new record?
Are records that were added by `Append()` automatically cancelled, when they are left unchanged after the `OnNewRecord` event?

regards and thanx

Herwig

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the difference between `TDataSet`'s `OnNewRecord` and `AfterInsert` event handlers is:

- Editing fields values from the `OnNewRecord` will **NOT** flag the record as modified
- Editing fields values from the `AfterInsert` will flag the record as modified

I guess that this is the cause of the problem